# Missing Image Fipboard

Tags: flipboard

I was using Flipboard without issues for years. Since a few months there is no featured image in flipboard.app anymore. But the same image is displays on Desktop without problems.

I have tried:

- deactivating ShortPixel
- changing the image size
- allowing Flipboard in the robots.txt

Nottingham works. The featured image doesn't appear on the App.

Does anyone knows that issue?

Greetings K.